# chrome shows a warining of youtube embed url in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, embed

Please any one help me.Google chrome shows a warning when it loads a iframe tag which contains a youtube url.The warning is shown below,

www-embed-player.js:277 GET https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Answer (score 4):

That error must be showing because of an Adblock extension.

Try to disable your Adblock or try in another browser without Adblock.

Comment: How to Disable Adblock in chrome

Comment: You have an icon in the top right corner of your browser with a red hand, just press and click Stop Adblock

Comment: [Here you have](https://www.enkivillage.org/how-to-disable-adblock-on-chrome.html)

Comment: Oh..Thanks let me check